# Cut-off Subtraction in Coq

Tags: logic, computer-science, self-learning, computer-assisted-proofs

I am new to the world of computer assistant proof programs in general, and Coq in particular. As a result, I have sought to prove some elementary results about integers as a way to … At the moment, I am dealing with cut-off subtraction. This I have defined in Coq to be:

Definition monus (m n:N):N := R (fun x=> N) m (fun x y=> pd y) n.

where pd represents the predecessor function

Definition pd (n: N): N :=
R (fun _=> N) zero (fun x y=> x) n

> What I want to accomplish is to first prove that for all $m,n \in\mathbb{N}$ \begin{equation} S(m)-S(n)=m-n \tag{*}\end{equation}
>   and then prove \begin{equation} (m+n)-n=m \tag{**} \end{equation}

These are displayed in Coq as:

1. Lemma monus_eq3 : (forall m n:N, I N (monus (succ m) (succ n)) (monus m n)).
2. Lemma monus_eq4 : (forall m n:N, I N (monus (add m n) n) m).

This is what I have managed to write at this stage:

> ```
> (* Sigma types *)
>
>
> Inductive Sigma (A:Set)(B:A -> Set) :Set :=
>   Spair: forall a:A, forall b : B a,Sigma A B.
>
> Definition E (A:Set)(B:A -> Set)
>   (C: Sigma A B -> Set)
>   (c: Sigma A B)
>   (d: (forall x:A, forall y:B x, 
>       C (Spair A B x y))): C c :=
>
> match c as c0 return (C c0) with
> | Spair a b => d a b
> end. 
>
>
> (* Binary sum type *)
>
> Inductive sum' (A B:Set):Set := 
> inl': A -> sum' A B | inr': B -> sum' A B.
>
> Print sum'_rect.
>
> Definition D (A B : Set)(C: sum' A B -> Set)
> (c: sum' A B)
> (d: (forall x:A, C (inl' A B x)))
> (e: (forall y:B, C (inr' A B y))): C c :=
>
> match c as c0 return C c0 with
> | inl' x => d x
> | inr' y => e y
> end.
>
> (* Three useful finite sets *)
>
> Inductive N_0: Set :=.
>
> Definition R_0
>   (C:N_0 -> Set)
>   (c: N_0): C c :=
> match c as c0 return (C c0) with
> end.
>
> Inductive N_1: Set := zero_1:N_1.
>
> Definition R_1 
>   (C:N_1 -> Set)
>   (c: N_1)
>   (d_zero: C zero_1): C c :=
> match c as c0 return (C c0) with
>   | zero_1 => d_zero
> end.
>
> Inductive N_2: Set := zero_2:N_2 | one_2:N_2.
>
> Definition R_2 
>   (C:N_2 -> Set)
>   (c: N_2)
>   (d_zero: C zero_2)
>   (d_one: C one_2): C c :=
> match c as c0 return (C c0) with
>   | zero_2 => d_zero
>   | one_2  => d_one
> end.
>
>
> (* Natural numbers *)
>
> Inductive N:Set :=
> zero: N | succ : N -> N.
>
> Print N. 
>
> Print N_rect.
>
> Definition R 
>   (C:N -> Set)
>   (d: C zero)
>   (e: (forall x:N, C x -> C (succ x))):
>   (forall n:N, C n) :=
> fix F (n: N): C n :=
>   match n as n0 return (C n0) with
>   | zero => d
>   | succ n0 => e n0 (F n0)
>   end.
>
> (* Boolean to truth-value converter *)
>
> Definition Tr (c:N_2) : Set :=
> match c as c0 with
>   | zero_2 => N_0
>   | one_2 => N_1
> end.
>
> (* Identity type *)
>
> Inductive I (A: Set)(x: A) : A -> Set :=
> r :  I A x x.
>
> Print I_rect.
>
> Theorem J 
>   (A:Set)
>   (C: (forall x y:A, 
>               forall z: I A x y, Set))
>   (d: (forall x:A, C x x (r A x)))
>   (a:A)(b:A)(c:I A a b): C a b c.
> induction c.
> apply d.
> Defined.
>
> (* functions are extensional wrt
>   identity types *)
>
> Theorem I_I_extensionality (A B: Set)(f: A -> B):
> (forall x y:A, I A x y -> I B (f x) (f y)).
> Proof.
> intros x y P.
> induction P.
> apply r.
> Defined.
>
>
> (* addition *)
>
> Definition add (m n:N) : N 
>  := R (fun z=> N) m (fun x y => succ y) n.
>
> (* multiplication *)
>
> Definition mul (m n:N) : N 
>  := R (fun z=> N) zero (fun x y => add y m) n.
>
>
> (* Axioms of Peano verified *)
>
> Theorem P1a: (forall x: N, I N (add x zero) x).
> intro x.
> (* force use of definitional equality
>   by applying reflexivity *)
> apply r.
> Defined.
>
>
> Theorem P1b: (forall x y: N, 
> I N (add x (succ y)) (succ (add x y))).
> intros.
> apply r.
> Defined.
>
>
> Theorem P2a: (forall x: N, I N (mul x zero) zero).
> intros.
> apply r.
> Defined.
>
>
> Theorem P2b: (forall x y: N, 
> I N (mul x (succ y)) (add (mul x y) x)).
> intros.
> apply r.
> Defined.
>
> Definition pd (n: N): N :=
> R (fun _=> N) zero (fun x y=> x) n.
>
> (* alternatively
> Definition pd (x: N): N :=
> match x as x0 with
>   | zero => zero
>   | succ n0 => n0
> end.
> *)
>
> Theorem P3: (forall x y:N, 
> I N (succ x) (succ y) -> I N x y).
> intros x y p.
> apply (I_I_extensionality N N pd (succ x) (succ y)).
> apply p.
> Defined.
>
> Definition not (A:Set): Set:= (A -> N_0).
>
> Definition isnonzero (n: N): N_2:=
> R (fun _ => N_2) zero_2 (fun x y => one_2) n.
>
>
> Theorem P4 : (forall x:N, 
> not (I N (succ x) zero)).
> intro x.
> intro p.
>
> apply (J N (fun x y z => 
>     Tr (isnonzero x) -> Tr (isnonzero y))
>     (fun x => (fun t => t)) (succ x) zero)
> .
> apply p.
> simpl.
> apply zero_1.
> Defined.
>
> Theorem P5 (P:N -> Set):
> P zero -> (forall x:N, P x -> P (succ x))
>    -> (forall x:N, P x).
> intros base step n.
> apply R.
> apply base.
> apply step.
> Defined.
>
> (* I(A,-,-) is an equivalence relation *)
>
> Lemma Ireflexive (A:Set): (forall x:A, I A x x).
> intro x.
> apply r.
> Defined.
>
> Lemma Isymmetric (A:Set): (forall x y:A, I A x y -> I A y x).
> intros x y P.
> induction P.
> apply r.
> Defined.
>
> Lemma Itransitive (A:Set): 
> (forall x y z:A, I A x y -> I A y z -> I A x z).
> intros x y z P Q.
> induction P.
> assumption.
> Defined.
>
>
> Lemma succ_cong : (forall m n:N, I N m n -> I N (succ m) (succ n)).
> intros m n H.
> induction H.
> apply r.
> Defined.
>
> Lemma zeroadd: (forall n:N, I N (add zero n) n).
> intro n.
> induction n.
> simpl.
> apply r.
> apply succ_cong.
> auto.
>
> Defined.
>
> Lemma succadd: (forall m n:N, I N (add (succ m) n) (succ (add m n))).
> intros.
> induction n.
> simpl.
> apply r.
> simpl.
> apply succ_cong.
> auto.
>
> Defined.
>
> Lemma commutative_add: (forall m n:N, I N (add m n) (add n m)).
> intros n m; elim n.
> apply zeroadd.
> intros y H; elim (succadd m y).
> simpl.
> rewrite succadd.
> apply succ_cong.
> assumption.
>
>
> Defined.
>
> Lemma associative_add: (forall m n k:N, 
> I N (add (add m n) k) (add m (add n k))).
> intros m n k.
> induction k.
> simpl.
> apply Ireflexive.
> simpl.
> apply succ_cong.
> assumption.
> Defined.
>
> (* modified subtraction *)
>
> Definition monus (m n:N):N := R (fun x=> N) m (fun x y=> pd y) n.
>
> Lemma monus_eq1 :
> (forall n:N, I N (monus n zero) n).
> intro m.
> induction m.
> apply Ireflexive.
> simpl.
> apply Ireflexive.
>
> Defined.
>
> Lemma monus_eq2 :
> (forall m:N, I N (monus zero m) zero).
> intro m.
> induction m.
> apply Ireflexive.
> simpl.
> (* induction IHm. fails - try apply to the symmetric equality *)
> assert (I N zero (monus zero m)) as IHm_symm.
> apply Isymmetric.
> assumption.
> induction IHm_symm.
> apply Ireflexive.
>
> Defined.
>
> Lemma monus_eq3 :
> (forall m n:N, I N (monus (succ m) (succ n)) (monus m n)).
> intros.
> induction m.
> simpl.
>
>
> (* Here is where I need your help *)
>
>
>
> Lemma monus_eq4 :
> (forall m n:N, I N (monus (add m n) n) m).
>
> (* Here as well *)
> ```

My problem starts when I induct on Lemma monus_eq3; I literally get stuck immediately(!). The goal is not in a form in which I can use any of my previous results. That is why I am now, after some considerable effort, turn to you in the hope that you may be so kind as to relieve me from this frustrating "stuck state". All help is sincerely appreciated!

Comment: Maybe this question is misplaced; would it be better if it was moved to stack overflow?

Comment: I doubt it would find more takers at SO. Even though Coq is to some extent "programming", it looks like expressing your ideas in its particular syntax is not your problem. It might help people (such as myself) help you here if you assumed less familiarity with Coq, and e.g. presented your primitive recursive (right?) definitions for monus and pd in mathematical notation rather than depending on the reader knowing how the `R` combinator works.